# Using CGI in python 3.4 I keep getting "End of script output before headers: measurement.py" error in my error log

Tags: python, cgi

The purpose is to have the area method return json serialized data using cgi and restful services. When I run request_area() my console displays 500 internal server error and when I check my error log it says 'End of script output before headers: measurement.py'

Here is measurement.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
__author__ = 'charles'

import json
import logging

import db_utility, db_access


def send_data(data):
    logging.debug(str(data))
    dataJ = json.dumps(data)
    logging.debug("custJ " + str(dataJ))
    lng = len(dataJ)
    logging.debug("len " + str(lng))
    print("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8")
    print("Content-Length: " + str(lng))
    print()
    print(dataJ)


def area():
    areas = db_access.get_all_areas()
    # print(areas)
    send_data(areas)
```

And here is request_area()

```
import requests

r = requests.get("http://localhost/cgi-bin/measurements_rest/measurement.py/area")
print(r.text)
```

Oh and the function being called in area(), get_all_areas()

```
def get_all_areas():
    """
    Returns a list of dictionaries representing all the rows in the
    area table.
    """
    cmd = 'select * from area'
    crs.execute(cmd)
    return crs.fetchall()
```

I can not figure out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: isnt there some web server log file you can look at?

Comment: I did look at it. That is where I got the error message 'End of script output before headers: measurement.py' from.

Comment: duh. sorry, not thinking straight. What framework are you using? What is going to call `area()`? Apache is going to stop with running `measurement.py`, so what is parsing the /area and matching it to your function?

Comment: All that is being used is cgi on an apache2 server. I am fairly new to all of this so I am not sure what will actually parse the area function.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using apache to call your program, apache will place in the
environment several variables with info on the cgi call and the url.

The one of interest to you is PATH_INFO which contains the string remaining
unparsed by apache, ie `area`.  In your python main you need to
`os.getenv('PATH_INFO')` and recognised the word and call your function.

Alternatively, use a framework like [cherrypy](http://cherrypy.org/) which
does this sort of work for you.

Also, you are printing stuff before the `Content-type` etc headers. Remove

```
print(areas)
```

Comment: @CharlesDriverJr. Yes, it didnt get there yet. My mistake. I've added what I think you need to do. Currently no-one is calling any functions, so the script runs but outputs nothing back to apache.